# JqueryUI tooltip position based on screen

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui, tooltip, jquery-ui-tooltip

I'd like to know if there's a way to set different positions of the jQueryUI tooltip based on different screen size. I'm using this code **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XFKN2/)**

```
$(function () {
    $(document).tooltip({
        position: {
            my: "left+120 top",
            at: "center top"
        },
        content: function () {
            return $(this).prop('title');
        },
        show: null, 
        close: function (event, ui) {
            ui.tooltip.hover(

            function () {
                $(this).stop(true).fadeTo(400, 1);
            },

            function () {
                $(this).fadeOut("300", function () {
                    $(this).remove();
                })
            });
        }
    });
});
```

It looks fine on larger screens but way too high at 800X600. Can I set different positions based on screen resolution?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the width of the window using `$(document).width();` and then have two different positions and/or styles to the tooltip depending on if the width is bigger or smaller than your wanted breakpoint.

Comment: You can set different position options for different widths. The position option can be set after initialization as follows:
$( ".selector" ).tooltip( "option", "position", { my: "left+15 center", at: "right center" } );